# Shared preferences in a service and in an Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application a service is running in the background periodically checking if an event occurs (we are over a given timestamp). If the event occured it sets a boolean (`DisplayStatus`)in the shared preferences.

In my `MainActivity.onStart()` I'm checking the value of this boolean and based on its value I either display or hide some ImageViews. So I would expect that once the service sets the DisplayStatus to true I can leave my app with the home button (so it stays in memory) then if I restart it and I would see the images. This does not happen though.

I know for sure that my background service works fine as it also sends a notification when it sets the boolean to true, but the ImageViews only get displayed if I swipe the application from the memory and restart it. If I simply leave the application and the restart it doesn't display the images.

After googling the topic some suggest to use .commit() instead of .apply() when I write the boolean to the shared preferences, but this doesn't make any difference in my case, the app needs to be swiped out from the memory to display the images.

MainActivity:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (shared_preferences.getDisplayStatus(this)) {
        DisplayImages();
    } else {
        HideImages();
    }
}
```

My service:

```
private void CheckIfNotification() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > GetTime.GetTimeInMillis(Globals.STARTDATE)) {
        if (!shared_preferences.getDisplayStatus(ctx)) {
            shared_preferences.setDisplayStatus(ctx, true);
            myNotification(ctx, "This a notification");
        }
    } else {
        shared_preferences.setDisplayStatus(ctx, false);
    }
}
```

My class to set/get the shared preferences:

```
public static void setDisplayStatus(Context ctx, boolean displayStatus) {
    ctx.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("DisplayStatus", displayStatus).commit();
}

public static boolean getDisplayStatus(Context ctx) {
    return ctx.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("DisplayStatus", false);
}
```

Comment: I guess place some code on `onResume` for checking the value you want to be checked once you return to the app.

Comment: That wouldnt make any difference.

Comment: It'll make a difference. `onStart` isn't called again if you return to the app after you pressed the Home button while `onResume` will be called. Look at Figure 1 of https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @Istvanb have you tried PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Default shared preference of android. I think its happens because of multi context of sharedpreference.

Comment: @rmanalo Actually it does... when you press the home button the onPause and onStop methods will be called. When restarting the app previously put to the background the onRestart, onStart, onResume methods are called.

Comment: AFAIK, it's best to place code you want to be executed everytime an app returns to screen on `onResume`. I don't use `onStart` on my code.

Comment: Of course I can put that code to the onResume, but because my app has only one activity, it would make zero difference.

Comment: @Mahesh Keshvala can you elaborate on this a bit more? Yeah, maybe the different contexts can cause an issue (I dont know, but its suspicious), but I can't call PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) in my class as it's this doesnt refer to a context. (its just a simple class). At least this is my understanding.

Comment: @Istvanb you are working on activity and service and both returns its context so either you can pass this or context. it doesn't make any difference in that.

Comment: @Mahesh Keshvala so I have replaced `ctx.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)` with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx)`. Unfortunately nothing changed. By mistake I wrote 'service' but what is running in the background is actually a broadcastreceiver. Not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: Have you tried using `onResume`? Please, it won't hurt to try it.